# Is there any relationship with ER and class diagram?

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram

Can I convert my ER diagram to class diagram directly by converting entities in to the classes?

Answer (score 3):

Almost.

OO class diagram is more abstract and has more features than ER diagram. ER diagram is kind of implementation of OO diagram.

- Most of the stand alone tables can be translated directly to OO classes with corresponding attributes
- Aggregate tables (the ones that only contain FKs) will be mapped to an N-N association between the corresponding tables/classes.
- FKs map to 1-N and 1-1 associations
- It is also possible to look for some patterns of tables and their keys to discover possible inheritances
- depending on further FK restrictions , association can also be compositions

There are a lots or sources about this on internet, just google "transforming object oriented data model to relational data model".

Answer (score 0):

There are techniques that allow you to convert almost automatically between data models such as entity-relationship and OO classes, and vice versa. However, if you want correct results, don't do this. On the data modeling side you have relational models (for the design of relational databases), ER models (a richer, higher level technique that adds semantics) or event better methods such as NIAM and ORM. But object oriented analysis is a completely different world with another way of thinking that allows you to create very complex models. I like to view ER diagrams and OO class diagrams as two **alternative** approaches. So **if you want to convert an ER model to an OO model, rethink your analysis**.  To reverse engineer your relational database to an OO class diagram, be sure you have a complete logical/conceptual analysis document at hand, because a lot of information is lost during implementation.
By the way: the double mapping OO classes-to-entities-to-relations may be tempting because some tool supports this as a quick and dirty approach, but I would definitely not recommend it.

Comment: A little comment on the answer of Aleks (I cannot comment there because I am new on stackoverflow and do not have a sufficient score yet). Please keep in mind that entities (ER), relations (relational model) and tables are different things.